# Tkinter entry widget get is undefined, not updating to my main function,

Tags: python, class, object, user-interface, tkinter

i'm following a few different guides to re-learn Tkinter by writing a little application that grabs stock prices. My issue that I am up a wall against is calling the .get() method from my entry widget variable. I've seen a couple other suggestions to put all the widget creating inside a function and then call the function in the init method, however I'm getting the same error, even when using the self argument in front of my entry variables. I know it's an issue with the way i'm passing data from function to function, but I can't wrap my head around it. Here's the code, sorry for the wall of text:

```
class MyApp:
  def __init__(self, parent):
    self.myParent = parent
    self.myContainer1 = Frame(parent)
    self.myContainer1.pack()
    self.createWidgets()

    button1 = Button(self.myContainer1, command = self.button1Click)
    button1.configure(text = "get quote")
    button1.pack()

  def createWidgets(self):
    root.title("Stock App")

    self.symbol = Entry(self.myContainer1)
    self.symbol.pack()
    self.symbol.focus_set()

  def button1Click(self):
    stock = symbol.get()
    print stock
```

I've taken it down to simplest form even and just had the button1Click call a callback function-

```
    def button1Click(self):
        print callback()

def callback():
    print symbol.get()
```

This returns the exact same error:
NameError: global name 'symbol' is not defined

Is it getting destroyed too early? how do I fix this?

I've referenced multiple documents for tkinter and have seen some great fixes but none are extensible, or um unable to see how they relate to me using it inside of an object.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell inside of your button1Click method you need to add self as in:

```
def callback():
    print self.symbol.get()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `self.` to make the callback:

```
def callback():
    print self.symbol.get()
```

instead.